# Media browser field in magento2

Tags: magento2, php, admin, file-upload

I'm currently trying to create (or find how to) a field to display the Media browser (or media storage manager) in admin Edit on a custom module.

Type file / image work fine, but it could be much more efficient if this button open the panel like in the wysiwyg. I see the javascript call in the wysiwyg

`javascript:openBrowser('filebrowser','src', 'media','media_media_browser_callback');`

but i didn't find a way to call that out of this field.

Have anyone done that before ?

Answer (score 0):

So, since i needed it, i made it :
https://github.com/Losams/Magento-2-Media-storage-field/

A new magento2 element form field to display what i want only.
It's a first thing, not really beautiful but it work. Feel free to use it.